# What is the disadvantage of Java not having real properties?

Tags: java

So, it's said quite often it's a disadvantage of Java that it does not have properties like [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28VS.80%29.aspx)

What advantage, over the getXX/setXX java-bean style properties would we get if Java gets "native" support for properties ?

Comment: So, it is quite often said that ... global warming is a hoax.

Answer (score 8):

Properties are nice syntactic sugar, but nothing more.

As a C# coder I'd miss them if they were suddenly taken away from C#, but I don't miss them that much when using another language.

Answer (score 4):

Who said you can't have such properties in Java? [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/index.html) makes it real.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's way overblown.

I'll agree that changes in C# are nice (e.g., closures, delegates, etc.), but anyone who's writing Java without an IDE that easily generates all the getters/setters you need automatically is crazy.  It's simply not a big deal.

Comment: anyone that is using a language that needs tons of code generation is crazy :)

Comment: @Lie - it doesn't need it.  You can write Java using a simple text editor.  I did for many years.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft has never generated code, have they?  How many wizards have they foisted on the world?  Generating getters and setters is hardly "tons of code generation".

Comment: @Stephen C - I can make fire with sticks and stones, but I prefer having a stove at my house.  Yeah, an IDE isn't necessary.  I can write code with vi or emacs.  But I'd rather have an IDE.  Microsoft developers don't seem to mind having Visual Studio.

Comment: @duffymo - I know.  And I always use an IDE these days.  But the point I was making to @Lie is that Java does not **need** an IDE with fancy code generation stuff.

Comment: @Stephen C - I just can't believe that people still get worked up about getters and setters.  C# is a lovely language, but the new properties syntax they came up with isn't solving world hunger.  Some people seem to be waiting for Anders' Nobel announcement in honor of it.

Comment: @duffymo: if you're talking about attribute and property syntax, then look at python's, not C#. C#'s property syntax is neat compared to getter/setter, but it still requires typing unnecessary boilerplate. In Python, you don't even need to type anything.

Comment: Agreed - I'm a Python guy.  But it's not a deal maker or breaker for either language.

Answer (score 1):

It's just shorthand syntax for the type of getter setter methods you write in Java.

int MyProp {get; set;}

It's nice to save a few key strokes when the code is so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

**Weaker semantics**

Compare this:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

with this:

```
private int foo;

public int getFoo() { return foo; }

public void setFoo(int value) { foo = value; }
```

The getters/setters say "there is a method to set something called Foo and a method to get something called Foo," but what's implied is "there is a property called Foo of type int." I think having language support to intuitively define exactly what you mean is a good thing. Java has the bean specification to define such thing... but why is there a *specification* for something that should be so natural? I agree it's not a *huge* deal, but it's certainly more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of being merely syntactic sugar, with properties in C# you can do somethings like this:

```
private string _theField;

public string MyProperty 
{
   public get { return _theField; }
   protected set { _theField = value; }
}
```

As well as:

```
public string MyProperty  { public get; protected set; }
```

Also you can overload the property, hide the base-class property by using the **new** qualifier preceding the property name... Particularly  I prefer to use properties (in C#) instead on C++ or Java Setters and Getters which are merely functions with special usage. Also if you use reflection in C# you can easily obtain the properties list by means of the **GetProperties**() function.